# How to split CSV dataset into training and testing set by percentage and save the splitted dataset into local folder with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, dataset, python-3.8

I have a large size CSV dataset and need to split training and testing set 77 % and 33 % respectively. Then finally I want to access each file in my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

## Importing the required library

```
import math
```

## The whole dataset

```
df = pd.read_csv('CTU.csv')
total_size=len(df)
train_size=math.floor(0.77*total_size)
```

## training dataset and test dataset

```
train=df.head(train_size)
test=df.tail(len(df) -train_size)
```

## Saving files

```
train.to_csv('train.csv')
test.to_csv('test.csv')
```